# Jenkins plugin monitoring for stuck jobs

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Does anybody know if there is Jenkins plugin that detects stuck jobs and e.g. sends an email?

I know that I can abort the build after n minutes (via the `Binding` configuration). My actual problem is that I've to check 60 projects and reconfigure each of them ...

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Build-timeout Plugin gives the option to stop build that answer specific configuration. for example if the build takes more than T minutes or if the build takes 3 times more than an average successful build.

Is that what you meant ?